# Different alignment in one column of longtable

Tags: horizontal-alignment, longtable

I have a longtable with this row

[image]

```
\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
\begin{longtable}{c|c|c}
...
$x^\alpha$ & $\frac{x^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}+c$ & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$\left\{\begin{tabular}{@{\ }l@{}} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3
\end{tabular}\right.$} \\ \hline
...
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

I need to let the brace on the left of column but I would like to have 1, 2, 3 in the middle of column. How to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Just the numbers, or the numbers and the brace?

Comment: Brace on the left, the numbers in the middle of column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand\MyBrace[1]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{$\left\lbrace\vphantom{#1}\right.$}\hfill$#1$\hfill\null}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{c|c|c}
...
$x^\alpha$ & $\frac{x^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}+c$ & \MyBrace{\begin{tabular}{@{\ }c@{}} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4
\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
a & b & some text and some other text
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]